# Not able to write GraphQL Mutation for creating a new user in database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, graphql

What I want to do basically insert new user in to database and return new user data using GraphQL Mutation. But I'm not able to insert data in to 
database. In the below image getting null values instead of new user data. Can anyone tell me where exactly my code is wrong.

schema.JS

```
type Mutation {
  createEmployee(input: EmployeeInput): Employee
}

input EmployeeInput {
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
    phone: String
    email: String
    name: String
    domainName: String
    smsID: String
}

type Employee {
    id: ID
    adminFirstName: String
    adminLastName: String
    adminPhone: String
    adminEmail: String
    smsID: String
    domainName: String
}
```

resolver.JS

```
import { employeesRepo } from "repos";

const mutationResolvers = {
    createEmployee: async ({ firstName, lastName, email, phone, businessName, domainName }) =>
    await employeesRepo.createEmployee(arguments[0])
};
```

employeesRepo.Js

```
async createEmployee(employee) {
let newEmployee = await this.employeeStore.insert(employee);
return newEmployee;
```

}

MongoStore.JS

```
async insert(document) {
   let db, collection, result, now;
   now = new Date();
   document.createdOn = now;
   document.lastUpdated = now;
   document._id = new ObjectId();
  try {
     db = await MongoClient.connect(url, options);
     collection = db.collection(this.collectionName);
     result = await collection.insertOne(document);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } finally {
     db.close();
   }
   return document;
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have defined your resolver as:

```
createEmployee: async (source) => await employeesRepo.createEmployee(source)
```

However you actually want to process the `input` argument passed to the field, which is in the second argument passed to `resolve`. Try instead:

```
createEmployee: async (source, args) => await employeesRepo.createEmployee(args.input)
```

See the `GraphQLFieldResolveFn` definition here:

http://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#graphqlobjecttype

```
type GraphQLFieldResolveFn = (
  source?: any,
  args?: {[argName: string]: any},
  context?: any,
  info?: GraphQLResolveInfo
) => any
```

Comment: I have added args in my resolver function but still getting same output. In my code I just passing fields to my resolver function. why do we need source and args. could you tell me precisely@Benjie

Comment: The arguments you pass to a field are available in the second argument passed to resolve; i.e. arguments[1] or "args". You're referencing arguments[0] (or "source") which is the resolved value of the parent field.